# Which one is faster to process between Math.pow() and using * operator several times?

Tags: java

Am writing a java program that raises different numbers to powers. Between Math.pow (8,4) and 8*8*8*8, which one takes shorter time to be processed?

Comment: Have you already tried to perform both computations, let's say 1,000,000 times using a `for` loop? (just to compare execution times)

Comment: well considering that they are doing the same thing...

Comment: @xav I've not tried using big numbers. Lemme try and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

Both the functions will be calculated in compile-time and would have the same efficiency.

Comment: Is there a way i can check the time taken for a function to be calculated?

Comment: That's another question. What have you tried to get it?

Comment: I've tried using big numbers and a timer but i can't observe a noticeable difference. I just to confirm the difference

Comment: 'course, you won't get it while making operations with one or two numbers. Make a bit data set: 1_000_000, for example

Comment: Lemme try that. Thanks

Comment: @ginz `Math.pow()` won't be evaluated at compile time and `8*8*8` may or may not be evaulated at compile time depending on how it is written in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Efficiency of Power function is greater than loop.You can check time taken for each functionility in following manner:-

```
    double i=10;
    java.util.Date dt=new java.util.Date();
    double z=(long) Math.pow (8,i);
    java.util.Date dt1=new java.util.Date();
    System.out.println("Using Power formula:"+(dt1.getTime()-dt.getTime()));
    double t=1;
    for(double k=1;k<=i;k++){
        t*=8;
    }
    java.util.Date dt2=new java.util.Date();
    System.out.println("Using loop :"+(dt2.getTime()-dt1.getTime()));
```

Comment: You can't measure such a fast operation with Date... See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Answer (score 0):

For simple operations like 8^4, a manual multiplication will be faster. A micro benchmark using [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) shows (nanoseconds/op):

```
Benchmark                 Mode Thr    Cnt  Sec         Mean   Mean error    Units
c.a.p.SO23595573.mult     avgt   1      3    2        3.074        0.022  nsec/op
c.a.p.SO23595573.pow      avgt   1      3    2       68.696        0.186  nsec/op
```

The code:

```
private int x = 8;
private int y = 4;

@GenerateMicroBenchmark
public double mult() {
    double result = x;
    for (int i = 0; i < y - 1; i++) {
        result *= x;
    }
    return result;
}

@GenerateMicroBenchmark
public double pow() {
    return Math.pow(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this small code

```
long pr=1;
long st=System.currentTimeMillis();
for(int i=0;i<200_00_00_000;i++)
   pr=pr*8;
long en=System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Executiom time  : "+(en-st));
```

It'll give you execution time for this code.
Do the same for **Math.pow(8,200_00_00_000)** and find the difference yourself.

**P.S** : `Math.pow()` executes faster.

Comment: -1 Your measurement is flawed (no warmup, you don't use the result of the operation etc.). see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java